# How to make liner service calls in rxjs or in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to achieve scenario like below
If 1st service has any values then it should return it
If 1st service is not having any response then it second service should be called.

How to achieve this in angular.. or is it possible to achieve it using RXjs operators

Comment: What does the 1st service return when there are no values? 404? empty array?

Comment: If first service returns empty observable then it should call second

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as simple as:

```
firstService.getValues().subscribe(received => {
    if(received != undefined){
        //do something
    }else{
        secondService.getValues().subscribe(received => {
            //do something else
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that if the first service is not available, request the second service for information and this can be done as follows

service.ts:

```
constractor(private http:HttpClient){}

getUser():Observable<any>{
  this.http.get('url_api_one').pipe(
   map((data:any)=>{
    if(data!=undefined)
      return data;
    return this.http.get('url_api_two');
   })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED AFTER UPDATE FROM QUESTION OWNER**

With RxJS you can use DefaultIfEmpty to catch the situation where you only get the complete (==EMPTY) message from the Observable.

```
  firstService(giveEmpty: boolean): Observable<any>{
    if (giveEmpty){
      console.log("1st service returning EMPTY")
      return of();
    }else{
      console.log("1st service returning something (1)")
      return this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    }
  }

  secondService(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5')
    .pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log('Succesfull 2nd service result', res))
    )
  }

  useService(use1stService:boolean): Observable<any>{
    return this.firstService(!use1stService)
    .pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log('Succesfull 1st service result', res)),
      defaultIfEmpty(undefined),
      switchMap(res=>res?of(res):this.secondService())
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.useService(true).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.firstSearch = res;
      console.log('SUB', res);
    });

    this.useService(false).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.secondSearch = res;
      console.log('SUB', res);
    });
  }
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkcygm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**OLD ANSWER WITH ASSUMPTION ON RETURN VALUE**

If you want to catch the situation with the 1st service returning a 404 Status use the below method.

```
searchItem(firstNumber: number, secondNumber: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + firstNumber)
    .pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log('Succesfull 1st service result', res)),
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          return of(undefined);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      }),
      tap((res) => console.log('After catcherror', res)),
      switchMap((res) =>
        iif(
          () => res === undefined,
          this.http
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + secondNumber)
            .pipe(
              tap((res) => console.log('Succesfull 2nd service result', res))
            ),
          of(res)
        )
      )
    );
}
```

When you search for something that is not found, catchError will check the status for 404 and then give an observable of undefined, that will be used in the iif in switchMap.

Calling it with a first value that doesn't exist will trigger calling the second service.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchItem(101, 5).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.firstSearch = res;
      console.log('SUB', res);
    });

    this.searchItem(1, 5).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.secondSearch = res;
      console.log('SUB', res);
    });
  }
```

first call will trigger a 404 and thus will call the 2nd service, the second call will just use the 1st service.

I've used JSONPlaceholder for this, where any id > 100 will trigger a 404 status.

See stackblitz for the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zffnsh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the 2nd service, if your service_1 delivers empty.

```
http.get(service_1)
  .pipe(
    defaultIfEmpty(undefined),
    switchMap((response) => response ? of(response):http.get(service_2)))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```